# Firefox and Edge doesn't use my CSS all/media/print when printing

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, printing, microsoft-edge

I have an HTML page with a data table and a morris graph apart from some h4 titles.

When I call JavaScript `window.print()`, Chrome and Safari print correctly, using the CSS and `@page` for the paper size.

Firefox doesn't use the CSS, just `@page` for the size, which is landscape as I set it up.

Edge doesn't use the `@page` or the CSS.

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: If you can provide a [mcve] of the HTML and CSS (you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to embed a runnable example here on SO), that would help in diagnosing the issue. You might want to look at [caniuse.com's listing of support for `@page` first, however](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-paged-media).

Comment: What is your CSS? Dont forget that Monzilla do have certain properties that need their own reference. In addition to that Microsoft might also have their own supported references instead - they are in the -ms library.

Comment: Thank you all, but the html rendered in the browser is correct, just not what is printed.

Comment: most of the browsers including MS Edge and Firefox has a basic support for @page. This can be the possible reason that your code is not working on FF and Edge. If you post your sample code than we can try to check your code and make a test with MS Edge to find any possible solution or work around. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page